# Get out-of-plane vector from two vectors and two angles

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

I am facing a linear algebra problem:

I want to calculate a (unit) vector $\ \overrightarrow{ AX }\ $ from a known point $A$ towards an unknown point $X$ in 3-dimensional Cartesian space.

Given are the vectors $\ \overrightarrow{ AB }\ $ and $\ \overrightarrow{ AC }\ $ as well as the angles $\ \angle BAX\ $ and $\ \angle CAX\ $.

I am aware that there are two points $X$ and $X'$ fullfilling the above mentioned conditions, that are mirror images with respect to $ABC$.
However, retrieving either of those points would already help me a lot.

Thank you for your help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIPtD.png)

Comment: The angles and fixed vectors give you two linear equations, and the unit length constraint gives you a second-degree equation in the unknown coordinates of $X$. Solve the system. Geometrically, intersect two cones and a unit-radius sphere.

Answer (score 1):

Set:
$$
\vec b={\overrightarrow{AB}\over|\overrightarrow{AB}|},\quad
\vec c={\overrightarrow{AC}\over|\overrightarrow{AC}|},\quad
\vec n = \vec b\times\vec c,\quad
\angle BAX=\beta,\quad \angle CAX=\gamma,\quad \angle BAC=\alpha,
$$
and write $\overrightarrow{AX}$ as a linear combination of base unit vectors:
$$
\overrightarrow{AX}=r\vec b+s\vec c+t\vec n. 
$$
Taking the dot product of $\overrightarrow{AX}$ with $\vec b$, $\vec c$ and with itself we find the equations:
$$
\cos\beta=r+s\cos\alpha\\
\cos\gamma=r\cos\alpha+s\\
1=r^2+s^2+2rs\cos\alpha+t^2
$$
You can then easily find $r$ and $s$ from the first two equations and plug the result into the third equation to get $t^2$.